# Firefox saving session storage history associated with navigation history?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser-history, session-storage

On Windows 10 I have a scenario similar to the following. Imagine a server that accepts a `POST` to `/random`, and it will generate an HTML file with the new random number embedded in the JavaScript. The JavaScript will dynamically display the number in the HTML, but it will also use `sessionStorage.setItem("random", randomNumberGeneratedFromServer)` to save the random number in session storage. This way if the user hits `GET` to merely reload the page, the JavaScript will see the random number in session storage and continue to show the same number in the HTML. (The page also uses `window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href)` to allow `F5` to reload the page using `GET` rather than `POST`.) It works across browsers.

Now let's say we have a "Regenerate" button on the same page that actually sends a `POST` back to `/random`. This will result in the same page getting generated, but with a new random number. The new page can also be reloaded, and it will find the *new* random number in session storage using `sessionStorage.getItem("random")`, and display it.

The downside is that regenerating the page using `POST` results in a new point in navigation history. If you hit the "Back" button, it will show the previous page. Unfortunately the previous page in navigation (which in reality is the same page with the same JavaScript) won't show the previous random number, because when used with `GET` the JavaScript looks for the random number in the session storage. Since the session storage variable was replaced upon regeneration, both the current page and the previous page will find the same number in session storage. The old random number is gone for good. Both the current page and the previous page will now show the new random number.

At least that's the expectation, and that's what happens in Chrome 116.0.5845.141. But in Firefox 117.0, when I hit the "Back" button to go to the previous page, it shows the old random number! I can even refresh the previous page, and it will show the old random number. And I can navigate forward and it will show the new random number!

Since both pages are identical and when called with `GET` they load the generated random number from session storage, I can only infer that Firefox is *storing different session values with different points in navigation history*! This makes no sense, as I had understood session storage to be independent of navigation history.

Is this documented behavior of Firefox to somehow store session storage snapshots associated with navigation history?

Comment: Are you positively sure that the JS really runs after history.back in Firefox? The symptoms you describe could be interpreted that browser just uses BFcache and shows previously rendered "static" state, without running JS. I guess if the JS ran, the (JS) sessionStorage would contain that new value. Have you checked its state through the console?

Comment: (Also, maybe reconsider your assumptions: what do you really expect seeing on the screen when you use "back in history" browser feature? Do you expect seeing the page in the exact state it was when you navigated away from it? Or do you expect seeing something different, technically even something that was never displayed before?)

Comment: I also thought that I might just be seeing a cached _rendering_ of the page, without it running the JavaScript. But then I would reload the page and it will still show the old random number! But I think I have figured out what was going on, and fortunately it looks like it wasn't the result of the session storage being saved in history. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimentation, it appears that Firefox is not actually saving a history of session storage associated with navigation history. What appears to be happening in Firefox is that it displaying the cached version of the previous page—the result of the `POST`, and running its JavaScript. Since the `POST` version contains the old random number embedded in the JavaScript, this results in the page re-saving the old random number back in the session state.

The moment I actually reload one of the pages in history in Firefox (using `GET`), this "locks in" the old value so that when I cycle back to the page it loads whatever is in the session storage instead of replacing it (as the cached JavaScript from the `POST` version did).

Chrome, on the other hand, does not seem to be using the old page from the cache, but instead actually issuing a new `GET`, which results in the old page retrieving the *new* random number from session storage as expected.

Firefox thus isn't keeping a history of session storage (whew!), but in essence *recreating* session storage history in sort of an accidental "event sourcing" because it is running the JavaScript on a cached version of the page.

Comment: This sounds plausible. If the HTML server response contained sth like `<script>saveRandom('first-generated-on-the-server')</script>` it would be preserved in the Back-Forward cache, so re-saved on next evaluation.
You should see whether bowser issues real network request in the devtools network tab in "Transferred" column (ensure "Disable cache" is *not* ON). (Or in your server's logs).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did. After writing the question, I remembered to look at the network activity in the dev tools, and that's when I saw that Firefox was using the cached version in history. (Note that it said `GET` even though in history it was never a `GET` but a `POST`, but as mentioned I had used `window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href)` so I guess that made Firefox store it in history as `GET`). In any case Firefox seems to have been using the cached version, while Chrome was actually issuing a new `GET`. I may have turned off caching in Chrome at one time.